# Selecting by tags while also returning all tags for the selected items

Tags: sql

I have the basic tagging table setup:

```
item (id, body)
tag_link (id, item_id, tag_id)
tag (id, name)
```

I can work out the JOIN to select for all items matching a list of tags:

```
SELECT i.* FROM item AS i
INNER JOIN tag_link AS tl
ON tl.item_id = i.id
AND tl.tag_id IN
  (SELECT tag.id FROM tag WHERE tag.name IN ('red', 'blue'))
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(i.id) = 2
```

The problem is that I also want all the tags associated with the selected items.

I ran across the `GROUP_CONCAT` function (I'm using SQLite), and came up with this:

```
SELECT i.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) 
FROM item AS i
INNER JOIN tag_link AS tl
ON tl.item_id = i.id
AND tl.tag_id IN
  (SELECT tag.id FROM tag WHERE tag.name IN ('red', 'blue'))
INNER JOIN tag AS t ON t.id = tl.tag_id
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(i.id) = 2
```

Which adds a field that looks like `"red, blue"` to each item returned. So far so good.

But if the items also have other tags associated with them that weren't part of the query, they won't get returned. **So my question is, how would I include ALL the tags for the returned items?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `having` clause instead.  If you want all the tags for items that have either `red` or `blue`, then use:

```
SELECT i.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) 
FROM item i INNER JOIN
     tag_link tl
     ON tl.item_id = i.id INNER JOIN
     tag t
     ON t.id = tl.tag_id
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING sum(t.name IN ('red', 'blue')) > 0;
```

Comment: Do you mean `count(t.name ...)` rather than `sum()`?

Comment: @PaulHicks . . . No.  I mean `sum()`.  That will count the number of tags that have one of those values.  `count()` would be equivalent to `count(t.name)` in this case.